# How to check TLS version of my Unix server

Tags: unix, ssl, ssl-certificate

We're trying to connect to a server but it's having the below error:

Sep 26 11:00:38 server name[8660]: conn=******** fd=*** closed (TLS negotiation failure)

I would like to know if the TLS version of my Unix server is compatible with the server we're connecting to.

Unix server is a Weblogic server.

Comment: Please provide more information - what kind of unix, what is the server software - apache httpd, tomcat or something other like jetty? Also whats the client you are using - is it curl?

Comment: Or do you forgot to open the firewall port for the ssl connection - normally 443?

Comment: Or do you have configured a different port to 443 - tomcat uses 8443 by default for example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using [Qualys ssl server test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) would help to find out what goes on.
Actual TLS versions are 1.2 and brand new 1.3 - older versions should no longer be in use. So verify what is the version of your ssl library and which tls versions they support. Please also note that not only the version could be a problem, but also the configuration of the supported CipherSuite's.
Also a missing firewall configuration could be the reason - for the case that you use a firewall on the server.
Also the servers ssl port could be configured differently - normally its port 443 - but tomcat uses 8443 by default.

Comment: Hi, this is a private server so I don't think it's going to work.

Comment: So you have to verify the ssl library versions of server and client to find out what they support and what ciphersuites etc. are configured on them.